# Properly type a callable returning a Generator expression

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance, pyright

I have the following snippet of code

```py
from contextlib import _GeneratorContextManager, contextmanager

GoodWrapperType = Callable[[int, str], _GeneratorContextManager[None]]
BadWrapperType = Callable[[int, str], Generator[None, None, None]]

def wrapper() -> GoodWrapperType:

    @contextmanager
    def inner(some_int: int, some_str: str) -> Generator[None, None, None]:
        # Do things with some_int, some_str
        yield

    return inner
```

I want to do this in the context of a `pytest` testing suite, where the wrapper is getting some fixture injected into the `inner`.

I have above the `GoodWrapperType`, and the `BadWrapperType`. Pylance is telling me that I can't assign the `BadWrapperType` as the return type of my `wrapper`. I have found a solution with the `GoodWrapperType`, using `_GeneratorContextManager`, but since it's prefixed with an `_`, I am not supposed to be importing it.

Is there a better way ? What's the proper way of doing this ?

I was wondering if the fact that there's no straight-forward solution (that I've found anyway), might be a hint that I shouldn't do this in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wrapper` doesn't return callable returning a generator function, it returns a callable returning a context manager, which is a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

`@contextmanager` decorator builds this class from the generator function it is applied to, but the end result is not a generator.

So we want to type `inner` as returning a generator function, but `wrapper` as returning a callable which returns the context manager that is the result of applying the decorator.

Here is a version which type-checks:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager, AbstractContextManager
from typing import Callable, Iterator, ContextManager


WrapperType = Callable[[int, str], AbstractContextManager[None]]


def wrapper() -> WrapperType:

    @contextmanager
    def inner(some_int: int, some_str: str) -> Iterator[None]:
        # Do things with some_int, some_str
        yield

    return inner
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6b2b3360a4916ec654a84ac84fcea544

If we're not using the send and return features of the generator we can simplify its type to just `Iterator[<yield type>]` as above.

`AbstractContextManager[<enter return type>]` is a generic type for context managers. (Note: pre Python 3.9 you should use `from typing import ContextManager` instead)

Since our inner function yields nothing, the type param in both cases is `None`.

However `contextmanager` returns a "context decorator", a dual-purpose class that can function as either a context manager or a decorator. Typing with `AbstractContextManager` will hide the decorator-ness of the result from downstream type checks.

If you need that property then your original approach with `_GeneratorContextManager` is probably the best way. (There is a public `contextlib.ContextDecorator` base class but [mypy lacks intersection types](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-1648409245) so there's no convenient way to type something as both an `AbstractContextManager` & `ContextDecorator` using only the publicly exported types).

Comment: Absolutely, I can't believe I missed the `@contextmanager` type difference between my inner/wrapper. For the moment, I don't need the yielded value from the inner, it's going to be setting multiple @contextmanager itself. Thanks for those insights